# aJMRTD : Gender , MALE ,FEMALE Cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, nfc

I have imported **aJMRTD** and all other required libs into eclipse,

But got some issues in **factory.java** file

Gender , MALE ,FEMALE Cannot be resolved.

Thanks.

```
public static PassportDO createPassport( MRZInfo m, Bitmap face )
{
PassportDO d = new PassportDO();
d.setDocumentCode( m.getDocumentCode() );
d.setDocumentNumber( m.getDocumentNumber() );
d.setDateOfBirth( m.getDateOfBirth() );
d.setDateOfExpiry( m.getDateOfExpiry() );
d.setGender( genderToString( m.getGender()) ) );
d.setIssuingState( m.getIssuingState().getName() );
d.setNationality( m.getNationality().getName() );
d.setPersonalNumber( m.getPersonalNumber() );
d.setPrimaryIdentifier( m.getPrimaryIdentifier() );
d.setSecondaryIdentifiers( m.getSecondaryIdentifiers() );
d.setFace(face);

return d;
}

private static String genderToString( Gender g ) {
switch ( g ) {
case MALE : return "m";
case FEMALE : return "f";
default:
    return "?";
}
}
```

Comment: in your class, is there a line like `import somethingsomething.Gender;`? ps: Ctrl+Shift+O in eclipse can make import statements for you

Comment: this is the project https://sourceforge.net/projects/ajmrtd/

Comment: So it's not your class, but still, is there an import? Where is that class or where should it be?

Answer (score 0):

You should typically also get an error that `net.sourceforge.scuba.data.Gender` could not be resolved. Probably you have removed the line

```
import net.sourceforge.scuba.data.Gender;
```

from your Factory JAVA class. The missing Gender class is part of the scuba_data library in the [aJMRTD code repository](http://sourceforge.net/p/ajmrtd/code/HEAD/tree/).